# Can I inject a CSS file programmatically using a content script js file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Can I inject a CSS file programmatically using a content script js file?

It is possible for me to inject the css when the js file is linked to my popup.html. The problem is I have to click on the button to open the popup to inject the css. I want it to happen automatically and in the background.

What happens in my code...

1. Get a variable from a MySQL database through a XMLHttpRequest
2. Call the function, "processdata()"
3. "processdata" Will process the data from the XMLHttpRequest. More specifically, split the variable, put it into 2 different variables and make them global
4. I call the function, "click()"
5. "click" Then will set the css after 1250 milliseconds using setTimeout
6. I use chrome.tabs.insertCSS to insert the css. The css name is the variable, "*currenttheme*"

As I mentioned before it does work using the popup. But the popup has to be opened before the CSS gets injected.

**How do I make this all happen *automatically, without any user interaction*?**

Here is my code:

```
    function getData() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        user_data = xmlhttp.responseText;
        window.user_data = user_data;
        processdata();
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8888/g_dta.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

getData();

function processdata() {
  var downdata = user_data.split('|||||');
  var installedthemes = downdata[0];
  var currenttheme = downdata[1].toString();
  window.currenttheme = currenttheme;
  click();
  }

function click(e) { 
      function setCSS() {
          chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file:currenttheme + ".css"});
          }
      setTimeout(function(){setCSS()}, 1250);
      document.getElementById('iFrameLocation').innerHTML = "<iframe src='http://localhost:8888/wr_dta.php?newid="+e.target.id+"'></iframe>";
      getData();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can programmatically create a new `<link>` tag and add it to the `<head>` section just like JS files are loaded dynamically.

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "http://example.com/mystyle.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Here's [an article](http://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/dynamically-including-javascript-and-css-files/) on the topic.

Comment: i have the impression you did that so easy...like make an answer with a ref without much effort. good answers come easy to experts...

Comment: @CrisStringfellow - Thanks Cris.  I knew the code to add a script tag dynamically and figured it was probably the same for a CSS file.  I did one Google search to confirm that and then wrote the answer.

Comment: Works for me. Good method to test external CSS on single page

Comment: Would this not create a flicker or FOUC since we are waiting for the document head (and thus presumably the entire document) to be rendered on screen before linking the external stylesheet?

Comment: @zr0gravity7 - Yes, it could cause a change in rendering when the new CSS loads.  Depending upon exactly why it's being dynamically loaded in the first place and what it contains, there are various strategies to protect against that.  The simplest idea is that the content defaults to not visible until this style sheet is loaded.

Comment: Update! Manifest V3 will not allow injecting files from external sources as shown in this answer. Only files contained in your extension package can be injected into the webpage. See @Divyesh [answer below for how to inject css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388005/1843673)

Comment: Note that you also need to add the css file in `web_accessible_resources` in yout `manifest.json` file. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554116/6908282

Answer (score 12):

## *Extension flicker*

A trauma to the ecosystem *that isn't hard to fix*

Preface:

Among many ways to get your css added to a page, most of them cause the screen to flicker - initially showing the page without your css applied, and then later applying it. I've tried several ways, below are my findings.

### The gist

You need to append a CSS `<link>` or a `<style>` tag in a [Content script injected on `document_start`](https://gist.github.com/2033842)

That code looks like this:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href =  chrome.runtime.getURL('main.css');
  //chrome-extension://<extension id>/main.css
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.documentElement.insertBefore(link);
```

For some dynamic CSS code:

```
var customStyles = document.createElement('style'); 
customStyles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
   'body { background-color: ' + localStorage.getItem('background-color') + '}'
));
document.documentElement.insertBefore(customStyles);
```

Doing this in a script on `document_start` ensures there is *no flicker!*

#### The reasoning

In this JavaScript file you can handle any number of programmatic things. The URL pattern matching offered in `manifest.json` is very limited, but here you can actually look at all the `?query_string` and `#hash` of a url, and use full regular expressions and string operations to decide whether or not to inject CSS. That CSS can also be based on settings, and/or coordinate with messaging to the background page.

### Parting words

- Don't use `.insertCSS`, you will notice a flicker.

Comment: I recommend [`chrome.extension.getURL('/mod/style.css')`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) over a hard-coded `chrome-extension://...` protocol + host.

Comment: I know, this is more of a blog post, but tell me what you guys think!

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL()` is deprecated since Chrome 58. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL

Comment: ```document.documentElement.insertBefore(link, null)```  otherwise you would get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: Why the use of `insertBefore`, rather than appending after?

Answer (score 1):

It's to simple you could add to the manifest's permissions field : See `web_accessible_resources`

```
 , "web_accessible_resources": [
        "mystyle.css"
    ]
```

and also add this in `content_scripts`

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["mystyle.css"],
        "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js","content.js","my.min.js"]
    }],
```

you also add same thing using Programmatic injection and [insertCSS()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS).

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(integer tabId, object details, function callback)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it loads first, and can't override other styles...

Comment: @pixelearth try to use `!important`. I agree it load first