# How to inject CSS using content script file in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to inject my CSS from JavaScript which is injected as content script:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js"]
   }
],
```

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345003/can-i-inject-a-css-file-programmatically-using-a-content-script-js-file) about injecting CSS, but I encountered a problem while using code from [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345038/272770). Here's my `script.js` contents:

```
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL("style.css");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

After I load some page this message appears in console:

> Denying load of
>   chrome-extension://phkgaaiaakklogbhkdnpjncedlbamani/fix.css. Resources
>   must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order
>   to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Is there any way to fix this? Or, maybe, some other way to inject a CSS from that JavaScript file?

Note: I can't include style sheet directly from manifest.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You could add to the manifest's permissions field; See [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).  So you would add this to the manifest:

```
    , "web_accessible_resources": [
        "fix.css"
    ]
```

---

See also ["Programmatic injection"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).  and [`insertCSS()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS).

For most applications, forget all that `createElement` code and just add the CSS file to the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches":    ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css":        ["fix.css"],
      "js":         ["script.js"]
   }
],
```

although I understand that you don't want to do that in this exact instance.

Comment: But I need to do some things related to this style sheet in JavaScript, so it's not a solution in my case.

Comment: Actually, the code shown in the question, would not generate that error, at least on the latest Chrome *release* (20).  Something's missing.  Is "fix.css" an actual file?  Where's it located? Link to the full extension code.  What version of Chrome are you using? ... Adding to the add to the manifest's permissions should work irregardless (the first link). Did you try that?

Comment: Here's the source code - [https://github.com/Tsukanov/CleanTube/tree/activation-feature](https://github.com/Tsukanov/CleanTube/tree/activation-feature). I tested it in versions 20 and 22, got the same result. And I'm not sure what to add in manifest.

Comment: I tried to add `"web_accessible_resources": [ "fix.css" ]` and it worked. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Will injecting CSS in this manner mess up with the CSS of the webpage?

Comment: @AmalAntony, it can if you are not careful. But it's normally not a big problem if you understand the CSS cascade and/or "scope" your CSS as much as possible.

Comment: how would i load sass?

Comment: @chovy, you need to ask a new question for that.

Comment: if the file is exist... would be it okay if value of href become : chrome.extension.getURL("template/jquery-ui.css"); ?

Comment: @gumuruh, See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL.  Ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: this is so great. I didn't have to create a link element using `document.createElement("link");`. Simply adding the `web_accessible_resources` & `content_scripts.css` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use element.classList.add("my_new_class") to add new class in the element and in css you can style that element by using the newly added class. So onClick only the class is going to be added and then only css for that element will run.