# How to inject a <style> into the head section of a page with a Chrome extension, using a content script

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to make a very simple extension, that inserts this;

```
<style>

span.watch-view-count:hover {opacity: 1;}
span.watch-view-count {opacity: 0;}

</style>
```

right before the body on any YouTube page I visit.
    I tried using content script to inject the code above, first I tried putting the code in a CSS file called `mycsscode.css` and adding it to my `manifest.json` file like this:

```
"js": ["script.js"]
```

but I'm pretty sure nothing happened, since I viewed the source and couldn't find the code anywhere.

Then I tried following the first method in answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) but I changed the script.js to script.css hoping it would work, but nope it didn't so I'm stuck.

This are the codes I have so far;
manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Youtube views Hider",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "description": "A plain text description",

  "permissions": [
    "*://youtube.com/*/",
    "tabs"],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://youtube.com/*/"],
    "js": ["myscript.js"]}
]
}
```

myscript.js:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.css");
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Note: I'm almost an illiterate when it comes to coding lingo, so please put it in layman's terms.

Comment: Your problem may be that you are putting CSS into a script tag. Try creating an element called `link` with the following attributes `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just inserting/changing CSS, don't even bother with that javascript.  Change the manifest to:

```
{
    "name":             "Youtube views Hider",
    "version":          "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description":      "A plain text description",
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "matches":      ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
        "css":          ["myCSS.css"]
    } ]
}
```

Where `myCSS.css` is just:

```
span.watch-view-count       {opacity: 0 !important;}
span.watch-view-count:hover {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

Note:

1. Changed the `matches` value to work on actual *YouTube* URL's -- Which usually have the form: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?...`
2. Note the use of the `!important` keyword.
3. If you insist on programmatic injection, see ["How to inject CSS using content script file in Chrome extension?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11553600/331508).

---

---

PS:  If all you really want to do is alter a page's look or CSS, [the Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) is the fastest easiest way to do that in either Chrome or Firefox.
There are also thousands of pre-made styles available at [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I just read that you say you are a coding layman. Creating an extension is the hard way.

An easier way is to add the Chrome extension called [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) to achieve page modification.

Here is a [nice tutorial](http://hibbard.eu/tampermonkey-tutorial/) to get you started with creating a script for Tampermonkey ( Greasemonkey in Firefox ).

This way to you don't need to worry about the mechanics of running a script on a page.

Comment: While I'm all for pimping Tampermonkey, this didn't answer the OP's question.  You might at least provide a simple userscript that altered the CSS (which would only take 3-4 lines of code, excluding the metadata).