# javascript append to DOM before DOM is constructed (head and body are null)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

Goal: hide youtube recommendations

Implementation: inject <style> to hide some css classes

```js
var styleEl = document.createElement('style')
styleEl.textContent = `ytd-rich-grid-renderer,ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer,ytd-comments,ytd-live-chat-frame{
  display:none !important
}`
document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
```

here, I append to head AFTER DOM is constructed, this works, but I see yt recommendations for 0.5 seconds before they are hidden



so I try to append BEFORE DOM is constructed, but

```js
console.log(document.head) //null
console.log(document.body) //null
document.appendChild(styleEl) // Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed
```

> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time
> document_start  
> string  
> Scripts are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.

my javascript is inside a content script

Comment: Don't use js script at all. Declare your CSS style using [css](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#static-declarative) key not `js`.

Comment: [How to inject a <style> into the head section of a page with a Chrome extension, using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793245/how-to-inject-a-style-into-the-head-section-of-a-page-with-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<html>` element itself may exist. It's not semantically proper, but you can append to it instead, and it will apply the CSS rules as desired.

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(styleEl);
```

Another option would be to add a MutationObserver to the `<html>` and append once the `<head>` or `<body>` appear.