# Chrome Extension - Edit Default HTML

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm using `jQuery` in a Google Chrome extension to overwrite a website's default `CSS`.

The default class for `.CatalogHoverContent` is `display: none;`, however when the class `.SmallCatalogItemView` or `.CatalogItemInner` is hovered, it changes to `display: block;`

I've attempted to prevent this by overwriting the style using the code below, however the website's default style seems to be overwriting this and the class `CatalogHoverContent` still isn't shown by default.

```
.CatalogHoverContent {
 display: block;
}
```

Is there an alternative way to edit the style, such as JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger is the CSS. There are `:hover` rules attached to the two `<div>`s in the screenshot below: `SmallCatalogItemView:hover` and `.CatalogItemInner:hover`:

```
.SmallCatalogItemView:hover .CatalogItemInner.BigInner {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.SmallCatalogItemView:hover .CatalogItemInner.BigInner {
    top: -10px;
}

.SmallCatalogItemView:hover .CatalogItemInner {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: auto;
    left: -10px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 130px;
    z-index: 6;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.CatalogItemInner:hover {
    position: absolute;
}

.CatalogItemInner, .CatalogItemInner:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

To *stop* this CSS from running, there are a few options:

- Use JavaScript to set the `style` property of each element:

  ```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".CatalogItemInner");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var el = elements[i];
      el.style.border = "none";
      // ...
      // Set the rest of the rules
  }
  ```
- Use JavaScript to edit the stylesheet (`document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].style.removeProperty()` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule)). This will take some fine-tuning, though. You have to get the correct indices. [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime)
- Remove the `CatalogItemInner` class. This may have unintended side effects.

  ```
  element.classList.remove("CatalogItemInner");
  ```
- Take a look at [this](https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) and overwrite all of the rules:

  ```
  // Something like:
  addCSSRule(sheet, ".CatalogItemInner", "border: none");
  // etc.
  ```

Comment: @TheCodesee I'm sorry, but what do you mean by that? If you need to know how to inject CSS, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553600/how-to-inject-css-using-content-script-file-in-chrome-extension

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your range of answers and I was able to refer to them when I experienced further issues!