# How to Inject HTML along with CSS and JS in a single HTML file? - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-plugin, prime-ui

My extension is intended to inject some HTML elements using local JavaScript libraries such PrimeUI, jQueryUI and its correspondent CSS stylesheets.

The best way I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334054/inject-html-into-a-page-from-a-content-script) to do so, is to inject the HTML as follows:

```js
// test.js
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/overlay.html'), function(data) {
    $($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');
}
```

```json
// manifest.json
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"options_page": "",
"description": "Test",
"browser_action": {
  "default_title": "Test",
  "default_popup": ""
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "js": [
    "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
    "js/test.js"
  ]
}
],
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "overlay.html",

  "css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "css/jquery-ui.min.css",
  "css/primeui-all.min.css",

  "js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
  "js/jquery-ui.min.js",
  "js/primeelements.min.js",
  "js/primeui-all.min.js",
  "js/main.js"
]
}
```

I have the required JavaScript libraries inside "js" folder in the root directory, for security reasons I do not retrieve them from a CDN.

**My HTML contains CSS and JS on `<head>` section, but the styles nor the scripts applies in any way.**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/primeui-all.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/primeui-all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/x-tag-core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/primeelements.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn-show" type="button">Show</button>
    <div id="dlg" title="Godfather I">
        <p>The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, ...</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
// main.js
$(function() {
$('#dlg').puidialog({
    showEffect: 'fade',
    hideEffect: 'fade',
    minimizable: true,
    maximizable: true,
    responsive: true,
    minWidth: 200,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Yes',
        icon: 'fa-check',
        click: function() {
            $('#dlg').puidialog('hide');
        }
    },
        {
            text: 'No',
            icon: 'fa-close',
            click: function() {
                $('#dlg').puidialog('hide');
            }
        }
    ]
});
$('#btn-show').puibutton({
    icon: 'fa-external-link-square',
    click: function() {
        $('#dlg').puidialog('show');
    }
});
}
```

The button is successfully displayed but with no events are attached nor styles.

i.e: if I inject this code on StackOverflow my button get the styles from SO and not mine.

I want to avoid as much as possible JavaScript for creating elements, or injecting tags programmatically, to separate the View from the Controller.

How can I manage to use my styles and scripts with my injected HTML as we do ordinarily? I have tried adding them to `web_accessible_resources`, and other manifest fields unsuccessfully.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I would love I could make an executable from this, but only providing the code still is not "complete". I hope this improves the question. Thanks.

Comment: It does improve the question. What does *main.js* have to do with anything (it is not otherwise referenced, except in `web_accessible_resources`)? Why are you parsing this HTML (including `<head>` and `<script>` elements, which will not be appropriately inserted using these functions)? Are you expecting the `<script>` tags to insert scripts (they will not, at least not inserted this way)? Why are you trying to insert scripts/CSS this way instead of using Chrome extension methods to insert them as content scripts?

Comment: `main.js` only controls `PrimeUI` elements to be properly displayed (basic snippet). I have only seen people injecting code through Chrome JavaScript API and I was trying to avoid it. But thank you for clarifying that it is the only way. Although I was unable to find the way to do it with JS. I have read the main Chrome Documentation, but in my opinion I find it unclear and disjointed information.

Comment: For security reasons (basic part of the specifications), you can not insert a `<script>` tag through any method that starts with text based HTML.  You have to programmatically create the `<script>` element (e.g. `document.createElement('script')`).

Comment: Trying to insert large amounts of code/libraries as into the page context using `<script>` tags has a significant chance of interfering with the current contents/JavaScript of the page. Is there a reason that you are inserting scripts into the page context? Normally, you would have these inserted scripts (and CSS) as content scripts (*manifest.json* `content_scripts`, or `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`/`chrome.tabs.insertCSS()`, not in the page context.

Comment: The reason is I was unable to interact with the HTML elements, simply inserting it as `content_scripts`. I have no real preference. But I take note about the cares to take. Thanks.

Comment: If you do insert `<link>` and `<script>` elements, you should keep in mind that their URLs will be evaluated from the point of view of the page (i.e. relative to the page URL, not the URL of your extension). Thus, you will need to use fully qualified URLs, which include the URL/scheme of your extension (i.e. as you are getting with `chrome.extension.getURL()`).

Comment: Well, that explains the flood of errors I did see on the console log before, regarding the paths (and forgot to mention). I take note about the cares to take. Thanks. What may I miss if is that simple as inserting the scripts and styles as `content_scripts`?  I will come with feedback after trying all the new information. Maybe if I remove the errors firstly, it may works.

Comment: There are things that don't exist well as content scripts. I have not tried primeUI as a content script. I would work on all of this as content scripts/CSS first rather than inserting `<script>` and `<link>` elements. While you *might* have to go that route (inserting tags), usually you only need to do so if you are directly interacting with scripts already on the page (e.g. wanting to run a function already in the page). As to being "unable to interact with the HTML elements", you should be able to interact with HTML. Exactly what was happening would require more detailed information.

Comment: While this may sound a bit contrary to my earlier comments, *Please* do not load jQuery and all of those scripts into `<all_urls>` unless you **have** to. That is a *lot* of code with which to burden *every single page* (what of those of us who have hundreds of tabs open?). It is possible you really *need* to load all of it into every page. However, even if your UI interaction is starting from within the page (one reason to use a *manifest.json* content script), try to architect the extension so only the minimum is loaded until the user begins interaction with your UI, then inject the rest.

Comment: Above you said "not in the page context", but I do not know what do you mean. I will continue tomorrow, I think you have provided the answer correctly, so I would like to accept your answer. If you are unsure after this long chat, I can edit your answer tomorrow if necessary. Thanks and regards.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Comment: With respect to page context vs content script context: The page context is the context which contains scripts loaded with the webpage. This is separate (with some sharing: e.g. the DOM) from the context into which content scripts are injected. Content scripts can [inject content (e.g. scripts) into the page context by adding elements to the DOM (e.g. `<script>` elements)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704/3773011). This is usually not needed. It should not be needed to manipulate the DOM. It is needed if what you want to do involves calling methods/functions already existing within the page.

Comment: I do not need to call any already existing JS methods within the page. I only need to style the HTML element I have injected. If I insert all the CSS and JS files just as `content_script`, it doesn not modify the injected HTML. That is why I am inserting `script` and `link` tags directly on page context. But also to be able to use `!important` CSS directive. Even though, if I insert jQuery as `content_script` I can use it in other files inserted as `content_script`, but not to modify the inserted HTML.

Comment: It seams like it might be a good idea to [ask a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with code along the lines of what you did originally (all the code injected as content scripts) and the CSS not actually styling the appropriate elements. If it is something that is specific to the libraries you were using, it could be quite beneficial to people using those libraries in the future to have a question that directly deals with using those libraries and (hopefully) has solutions which you, and they, could use.

Comment: I have read the architecture and now I have more clear what I am doing and what I can not do. I am injecting both HTML and JS via `content_script`. And after fixing many console errors, now I can check the network inspector, and finally see I have successfully injected all the files, but the HTML is not being styled. The way I do this is appending `link` and `script` childs to the `body` tag. On the other hand, I have appended the `HTML` to the body. All the resources are listed inside `"web_accessible_resources"`

Comment: I have noticed that refreshing the website I am injecting the code (i.e: duckduckgo.com) 1 per 10 times the code is styled and functions works. but the 9 remaining times when I refresh it does not work. Shall I ask a new question? I have answered the question with the main problem solved. You can post your answer if you want, I will accept it. Thank you @Makyen

Comment: I have realized my injections are asynchronous and randomly injected, so at the time it should detect jQuery, it misses the library. I can not find how to inject in sequence the libraries. I am using the answer's injection.

Comment: Given that you are already using jQuery, you could use `$(document.body).append(data);` instead of `$($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');`. This would not fix the problem of the URLs needing to be fully qualified URLs into your extension, but would insert active `<script>` and `<link>` elements. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2592092/3773011) includes code which will do so without using jQuery. Please understand that jQuery (and the code in that question) are specifically going around the security restriction of not inserting `<script>` tags from text (by converting text to tags).

Comment: Note that doing it that way does not give you references to the `<script>` and `<link>` elements which could be used to remove them.

Comment: In answer to your earlier question: Yes, what you describe would be a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Although, I would first try not removing the scripts as soon as they are inserted (as I mentioned in my comment on your Answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130305/discussion-between-makyen-and-roizpi).

Comment: I have opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087173/how-to-inject-files-in-a-queue-chrome-extension). Is there a reason to append it to the `body` element instead of the `head`? And what do you mean by "active script and link elements"? Cheers.

Comment: "Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130305/discussion-between-makyen-and-roizpi)" is a suggestion from the other person that this set of comments has become more of a discussion which should be done in chat rather than strictly focused on improving this question. If there is more that you want to cover here, then we really should continue this [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130305/discussion-between-makyen-and-roizpi). I have answered your questions [there](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130305/discussion-between-makyen-and-roizpi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makyen explained:

It is not possible to parse HTML with `<head>` elements hardcoded such `<script>` and `<link>`. Instead it should be injected in other way.

The ways I have chosen to inject the files are:

[For the CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553600/how-to-inject-css-using-content-script-file-in-chrome-extension):

```css
// Test.js

/** CSS Injection */
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL("css/jquery-ui.min.css");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

[For the JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879):

```javascript
// Test.js

/** JavaScript Injection */
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');
// "When an inline script is inserted in the document, it's immediately executed 
// and the <script> tag can safely be removed". – Rob W.
s.onload = s.remove;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

> Trying to insert large amounts of code/libraries as into the page context using  tags has a significant chance of interfering with the current contents/JavaScript of the page. Is there a reason that you are inserting scripts into the page context? Normally, you would have these inserted scripts (and CSS) as content scripts (manifest.json 
>   content_scripts, or chrome.tabs.executeScript()/chrome.tabs.insertCSS(). not in the page context. – Makyen

With the above code I have successfully injected the files, but the styles and functions are applied only sometimes, I will edit when I fix this.

Comment: Immediately removing libraries is not a good idea. The point of a library is that it is still around an available for your code to use it later. Rob W.'s comments/suggestion for immediately removing `<script>` tags was intended for scripts which execute and complete, not ones that are intended to be around to be used by scripts inserted later.