# Executing Javascript Inside of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm making a Chrome Extension that uses some TamperMonkey scripts that I made. I want to have one "main" javascript file, where you include and execute other scripts from it. I'm good with including the other javascript files in this main file by using the lines:

```
var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.src = chrome.extension.getURL('h.js');
document.head.appendChild(s1);
```

The main problem that I am having when using those lines is that it gets the code and adds it to the document head, but never executes.

[image: Chrome Sources]

The console output states:

[image]

So I guess my main question is; How can I get the code to execute so I can run assorted methods and classes from it?

Here is the "main" javascript file:

```
var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.src = chrome.extension.getURL('h.js');
document.head.appendChild(s1);

var posinstance = new Mark(document.querySelector("#postingbody"));
posinstance.mark(positive, {
accuracy: {
  value: "exactly",
  limiters: [".", ",", "!"]
},
separateWordSearch: false,
diacritics: false,
className: "positive"
});
```

And here is the script I'm trying to include:
http://pastebin.com/raw/ESL1xYZ7

Edit: Here is the manifest.json

```
  {  "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "exclude_globs":    [  ],
        "include_globs":    [ "*" ],
        "js":["jquery.user.js","globalVar.user.js","h.js", "word-highlighter.user.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "permissions":["tabs","<all_urls>"]

    } ],
    "converted_from_user_script": true,
    "description":  "did i do it right?",
    "name":         "Car Stuffs",
    "version":      "1.00",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery.user.js","h.js", "globalVar.user.js"]
}
```

Also I've read through that document you've linked me multiple times, Makyen. In my question I have included

- a specific problem or error
- enough code to duplicate the problem
- the desired behavior
- a clear statement
- all the error messages that I can find

What do you want me to do?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Read my edit @Makyen

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. The *manifest.json* helps. It provides *significant* information. A *manifest.json* is almost always needed in a Chrome extension to understand what is going on. It would be helpful if you specified the name for your "main" JavaScript file, rather than just saying "main". A large point of a [mcve] is that we should be able to copy the code in the question (and *maybe* use some clearly identified, commonly available libraries) into our own environment and duplicate the problem. Being able to do so without having to *guess* makes it much easier to help.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: Based on an assumption: That you are using the name *h.js* for a file that calls itself *mark.js* (based on your pastebin link), and which defines `Mark` helps make this a bit more confusing. If I am correct in my understanding that what you call *h.js* is really *mark.js* it would help make things more immediately understandable if you used the filename *mark.js*. Using *h.js* leaves doubt as to *h.js* actually being the thing that is defining `Mark`. Please clearly identify what the files you are including contain. As is, I am having to look at comments on your deleted questions to know.

Comment: @Makyen You didn't have to go to your previous answers at all. It literally says mark.js in the first two lines of the code, and the first 10 lines literally make the class Mark which I'm trying to execute. And even then, the script makes no difference what so ever. Write any code that you want to inside of a class named Mark, and you know what? It'll do the same thing.

Comment: The script is loaded asynchronously.  Add an `onload` handler to the script element, and put all the code following the `appendChild` into it.  See the `importScript` example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement).

Comment: @pat, that would certainly be an/the issue if this was a web page. The issue here is that from a content script, inserting a `<script>` inserts the script into the page context, not the content script context. Thus, even if the rest of the code was executing in a `onload` handler, the inserted script will not exist in the same context/scope as the code which inserted it.

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes, Part of my point is that the code for a [mcve] should be *included in the question*. In addition, it should be *minimal* and *complete* (sufficient to duplicate the problem). As you have said, almost anything could be in the file which defines `Mark`. That means that it could and *you should* reduce it to the minimum need to demonstrate the problem and include it in the Question (i.e. not a big hunk of code on some other site).

Comment: @Makyen I see what you are saying, I will try harder to follow what you are saying in the future. I'm testing out your solution as we speak and I'll report back. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This looks an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). You would probably be better served to take a step back and ask a question about the more general thing you are attempting to accomplish (your UI in the page with all scripts in the content script context), rather than the way you are currently attempting to accomplish it. Based on what I remember of your comments in previous questions, you ended up going down the path you are on, because having all your scripts in a `content_scripts` entry did not work. Better would be to ask a question about why that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

### `<script>` elements insert into page context, not content script context

Within a content script, you appear to be attempting to insert a `<script>` element into the document and then use the code sourced in that `<script>` element within your content script. That will not work. From within a content script, any `<script>` elements which you insert into the document cause the contained/referenced scripts to be loaded and executed in the page context, not the content script context. You will not be able to *directly* use any functions/objects/classes/etc. which are contained in the inserted `<script>` from within your content script.

If you do try to insert multiple scripts into the page context, you will need to account for the fact that they are loaded asynchronously. You can do something like is described in the answer to [How to sequentially insert scripts into the page context using `<script>` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092221/3773011). However, for what you appear to be wanting to do, this is not how to achieve it. You appear to want to dynamically load scripts into the content script context, not the page script context.

### Dynamically loading scripts into the content script context

If you want to dynamically load additional script into the context script context, you will need to [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to a background script instructing the background script to use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) to inject additional scripts. This is a desirable mechanic to use as loading all the files needed for an elaborate UI into every page is a heavy burden to impose on the user for the user interface to an extension which may be rarely used. If your UI is goign to start from within the web page, then it is much better to load a small bit of code into each page. That code can watch for the user beginning to interact with your extension's UI. When the user does begin to interact with your UI, the small amount of code can message the background script to inject the rest of the code needed for the full UI.

Comment: Hey, so I added this http://pastebin.com/raw/B1Cpaq0G to the top of my full script, and it states the same Mark is not defined error. I checked the <head> of the webpage, the scripts are getting included, and it seems they are executed AFTER everything loads. I checked this by typing in a variable or function from each javascript file, and it showed up just fine in the console

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes, You appear to have missed the point that inserting `<script>` tags into the document *will not* result in those scripts being added to the context in which your content script is running. `<script>` tags inserted into the document will load scripts in the page context, not the content script context.