# Issues with injecting jQuery into host page from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

[See my followup question for continued discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037922/chrome-extension-injecting-jquery-into-host-page-and-fixing-up-the-namespace)

I am writing a Chrome extension that needs to add code to the current browser page.  It does this from JavaScript code running in the extension sandbox with something like this:

```
$initializationTemplate.appendTo(document.body);
```

The $initializationTemplate variable contains the following HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log("prepare-jQuery is initializing jQuery");
    console.log("jQuery's type is " + typeof jQuery);
    window.MyChromeExtension_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    console.log("prepare-jQuery was successful...");
</script>
```

This does not work as, when my script is running, jQuery has not fully loaded yet.  I end up with one of two scenarios:

1) If the page had a previously existing jQuery include, I steal the page's jQuery for myself and the page's JavaScript breaks, or

2) If the page had no jQuery, my code breaks because jQuery is not yet defined.

If I add the following, on a page without jQuery, then I can hijack the jQuery for myself and (since I know the page doesn't use jQuery) everything is good.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        console.log("prepare-jQuery is initializing jQuery");
        console.log("jQuery's type is " + typeof jQuery);
        window.MyChromeExtension_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        console.log("prepare-jQuery was successful...");
    }, 200);
</script>
```

This is actually rather hit or miss since I'm downloading the whole of jQuery from the CDN, so if the download takes a second, my script still runs and finds no jQuery available.  If I set the timeout to 2-3 seconds then (at least on my relatively fast connection) I catch it all the time, but this really isn't an acceptable way to move forward.

I assume that these different script tags are being handled asynchronously due to the way Chrome is processing the HTML (see CSP discussion below) that I'm inserting into the host page.  This isn't an issue if I mock this scenario up as a stand-alone page (I did that just to prove that I wasn't doing something stupid).

I am using jQuery in the extension code as well (not from the CDN), but there doesn't seem to be any way to inject this same script into the page (you can't reference chrome-extension:// files in a script tag on the host page). Hence my use of the CDN link.

I would love to have a way of detecting whether there is already jQuery on the page, and I've tried examining document.jQuery to see if it's already loaded, but even with "run_at" set to "document_end" I always get "undefined" for document.jQuery.  Using the debugger I can see that the document is fully loaded with the  tags containing references to other libraries, but I have access to none of those JavaScript objects.

I can, of course, tell if jQuery is on the page from JavaScript I insert into the page, but this is too late since I can't then dynamically load jQuery if it doesn't exist (violates the extension security rules, though I don't get why I can put a script tag pointing to any old script file on the page, but can't do it programmatically).  I tried doing this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

And got this error (truncated for clarity):

```
Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ...'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 127.0.0.1:*".
```

I've thought about manually streaming in jQuery into the host page, but it just doesn't smell like injecting 100KB, more or less, is a reasonable solution to the problem.  I may try this next...

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Update(2017/02/03): Makyen answered a very similar question here: [How to sequentially insert scripts into the page context using <script> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087173/how-to-sequentially-insert-scripts-into-the-page-context-using-script-tags#)

Specifically, I have this bit of JavaScript to get the library to load and then run a bit of my code when it finishes:

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
$(document.head).append(jQueryScript);
jQueryScript.addEventListener('load', () =>
{
    console.log("prepare-jQuery is initializing jQuery");
    console.log("jQuery's type is " + typeof jQuery);
    window.MyChromeExtension_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    console.log("prepare-jQuery was successful...");
}, false);
jQueryScript.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/thirdParty/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js');
```

The rub is that while his method does load the script, and it does run my onLoad listener, setting window.MyChromeExtension_jQuery happens in the extension context and so isn't available to the code I've injected on the host page.

Also, note the order things must happen for the OnLoad to work (it has to be attached to the host page DOM before adding the listener or telling it which file to load).

Comment: See also [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

Comment: I'm also not convinced that you need to inject jQuery into the page context, and not the extension context.  What are you needing jQuery to do for you?

Comment: I use jQuery in the code that I'm injecting into the page.  I use jQuery on both sides of the sandbox wall, meaning in my extension and in the code I'm inserting into the page.

Comment: @ScottGartner, I would suggest that you create a new question. It is unlikely this one will be reopened. In the new question provide a link to this question, and the duplicate. Explain what you are still having problems with, including exact errors, or non-desired operation and describe teh desired operation. Provide a *complete*, but minimal, [mcve], including a *manifest.json* file. List the code by file name (not just unlabeled chunks of code), so we can understand what is where. Have enough code so that we can just copy-&-paste what is in the question and be able to duplicate your problem.

Comment: Just some info: The reason a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. Please help us to help you by providing a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @Makyen - It made sense, you'll find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037922/chrome-extension-injecting-jquery-into-host-page-and-fixing-up-the-namespace