# Loading libraries for use in a content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I created a Firefox extension that works, for the most part. I am having a hard time importing jQuery. I have downloaded it locally. I am getting no errors. So, sometimes the extension will work and jQuery will load. Sometimes it won't. Other times I have to reload the page 5 or 6 times to get it to work.

I am not a JavaScript developer and this is my first time attempting an extension. I have Googled and tried a bunch of things with no luck.

Below is my *manifest.json*

```json
"web_accessible_resources" : ["/jquery-3.2.1.min.js","/jquery.csv.min.js","/ui.js"],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128px.png",
    "48": "icon_48px.png"
  },
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_48px.png"
  },
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://*****.com/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }
],
"permissions":[
    "activeTab"
    ],
"homepage_url": "https://*****.com"

}
```

*content.js*

```js
function injectJs(link) {
    var scr = document.createElement("script");
    scr.type="text/javascript";
    scr.src=link;
    (document.head || document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(scr);
}

injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL("/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"));
injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL("/jquery.csv.min.js"));
injectJs(chrome.extension.getURL("/ui.js"));
```

Comment: Why are you inserting jQuery into the page using a `<script>` (making it available in the page context)? That's only something you would do in some special circumstances, which are unlikely to apply. If it is that you want to dynamically choose to *inject* jQuery, then that should be done using `.tabs.executeScript()` from the background page, which makes jQuery available in the content script context.

Comment: Are `"matches": ["https://*****.com/*"],` and `"homepage_url": "https://*****.com"` what you're really using, or are the `*****`  placeholder text intended to obscure the actual URLs?

Comment: Are you really wanting jQuery to be loaded into the page context? or are you wanting it loaded in the content script context? Are you really wanting jQuery loaded dynamically, or do you want it loaded every time your content script is loaded?

Comment: I am inserting jquery on the page because jquery.csv needs it. I have no control over the background page but the extension needs it.    Also, ***** is just a placeholder.

Comment: Also, this is my first attempt at trying to do something like this so I may be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: But, is there a reason that you are inserting jQuery, and jQuery.csv into the *page context* instead of using them in the *content script context*. Normally, you would use them within your content script in the *content script context*, not the *page context*. Inserting them in the *page context* has the likelihood of interfering with the web page's scripts. Unless you *know* you need them in the *page context*, then you almost certainly should only be putting them in the *content script context*.

Comment: Often, what you would do is declare all of the scripts you want to have in the content script context in the `"js"` key within the `content_scripts` key in your *manifest.json* (listed in the order you want them loaded). For example: `"js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "jquery.csv.min.js", "ui.js", "content.js"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would load jQuery by including it within the `js` key in your *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry. For example:

```json
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "jquery.csv.min.js", "ui.js", "content.js"]
  }
]
```

Scripts are loaded in the order listed. So, you need to list the libraries which depend on others after the ones they depend upon (e.g. `"jquery-3.2.1.min.js"` before `"jquery.csv.min.js"`).

#### What you were doing

The way that you were doing it inserted the scripts into the page context using `<script>` tags. Such tags are loaded asynchronously. Thus, there was no guarantee that your scripts which depended on jQuery were actually loaded after jQuery. For what you are doing, you *don't* want to be loading the scripts into the page context, which is separate from the content script context where your content scripts normally run. If you want more information as to how you can do that successfully, you can see my answer to [How to sequentially insert scripts into the page context using  tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41092221/3773011), which has fully functional code to insert multiple dependent libraries into the page context.

### Use [`.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) to dynamically load scripts when they are not used 100% of the time

However, if you are loading your content script into a large number of pages (e.g. `matches` being `"<all_urls>`", `*://*/*`, etc.), then you should use a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry to load only the *bare minimum* needed to show the initial portion of your user interface (i.e. just the static portion seen prior to the user interacting). Only once the user begins interacting with your user interface should you then send a message, using [`.runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage), to your background script, received using [`.runtime.onMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage), to instruct your background script to inject the rest of the files needed for your complete user interface. You background script would then use [`.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) to load the additional scripts you need and, perhaps, [`tabs.insertCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) to inject any additional CSS which you may need.

The point of doing the above is to minimize the impact your extension has on the user/browser during the time which the user is *not* actively using your extension, which is most of the time under most conditions.