# Manifest v3 Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I get this error even if "image/copy.svg" is properly declared in the manifest.json

> Denying load of
> chrome-extension://pofbdjeepddggbelfghnndllidnalpde/images/copy.svg.
> Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key
> in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

If I go to chrome-extension://pofbdjeepddggbelfghnndllidnalpde/images/copy.svg I can successfully see the loaded image.

**css/style.css**

```
.copy-icon{
    content:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/copy.svg');
    height: 16px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

**html**

```
<button alt="Copy to clipboard" class="clipboard" data-clipboard-text="TEXT">
  <img class="copy-icon"></img>
</button>
```

manifest.json

```
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"], 
      "js": ["contents/results.js"],
      "css": ["css/style.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["images/copy.svg"],
        "matches": [],
       "extension_ids": []
      }],
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `matches` key should specify where to expose these resources.
You can use `<all_urls>` to expose them everywhere.

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [{
  "resources": ["images/copy.svg"],
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
}],
```

Comment: Might be silly question, but Would this prompt user to give access to all sites?

Comment: No, this feature is about site-to-extension access, not extension-to-sites.

Comment: For me the error was I was setting the sources as ./images/copy, get rid of the . since it's not neccesary and it worked for me.

Comment: So I've tried everything(./content/, /content/, content/), but still get this error: 
`Denying load of chrome-extension://aimmlilnhffmbohdhgcehalocokocncl/content/templates/menu.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.` 

I'm trying to load an html template and my manifest looks like this
`"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "resources": [
        "content/templates/main.html"
      ]
    }
  ]`

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension and the tabs after editing manifest.json or the content script.

Comment: Reload the extension did the trick for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution didn't work for me. The file did not load. This below was an example that worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554116/12975352

e.g:

```
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["content.css"],
        "matches": ["<YOUR_URL>"]
      }],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<YOUR_URL>"],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": ["content.css"]
    }]
```