# Inject CSS File Into Page From Content Script (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to link CSS files to a page with a Chrome extension. It works when I refrence the files in "content_scripts", but I need to be able to add/remove the files at runtime without refreshing the page, so it won't work for me.

The code I'm using as of right now is able to link the CSS files, but the styles are not applied regardless of where I place them (head, body, documentElement).
This is the code:

```js
const target = document.head;

if (user_theme) {
    // Import CSS for dark mode
    const themeLink = document.createElement("link");
    themeLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    themeLink.type = "text/css";
    themeLink.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("/css/dark-canvas.css");
    target.appendChild(themeLink);
}

if (user_ui) {
    const uiLink = document.createElement("link");
    uiLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    uiLink.type = "text/css";
    uiLink.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("/css/styles.css");
    target.append(uiLink);
}
```

I already found this rather outdated StackOverflow question: [How to inject CSS using content script file in Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553600/how-to-inject-css-using-content-script-file-in-chrome-extension)

Their solution was to add an array called "web_accessible_resources" to the manifest file, but I got an error saying that a dictionary was expected.

Does anyone know how I could do fix this?

Comment: In ManifestV3 web_accessible_resources uses a different syntax, which is shown in the documentation, but if toggling of CSS is peformed in the extension popup or background script there's a better way: chrome.scripting.insertCSS and removeCSS.